# Use XSLT to wrap all nodes inside newly-inserted node

Tags: xslt

How do I use XSLT to transform this XML:

```
<root>
  <base_currency_code>ZAR</base_currency_code>
  <base_discount_amount>0</base_discount_amount>
  <base_discount_invoiced>0</base_discount_invoiced>
</root>
```

into this:

```
<root>
<items>
  <base_currency_code>ZAR</base_currency_code>
  <base_discount_amount>0</base_discount_amount>
  <base_discount_invoiced>0</base_discount_invoiced>
</items>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather trivial problem. You should have known the answer after spending an hour or less with an XSLT tutorial:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <items>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </items>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```